# How do you create your levels containing curved slopes in Box2d?

Tags: iphone, box2d, level-design, cocos2d, cocos2d-iphone

I have just started developing games for iPhone in Cocos2d and am currently working on a Box2D prototype. I know this is not an easy start, but I have experience in the AS3 port of the physics engine. And ... I am stubborn.

**My question is:**
How do you implement and create your levels in the project. Is there a good parser out there or maybe a nice approach you guys know of? I am looking for a way to create curved slopes and of course circles and rectangles.

I have read about LevelSVG but it seems to add a lot of functionality that I don't want. I am a Flash game developer and I am used to writing the game logic by myself. Is this product worth the money if all you need is the parser?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could port the Box2D SVG parser implementation from the Box2D forums (you said that you have experience with AS3) .

http://www.box2d.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=3073

It doesn't look bloated to me.